# Two databases and one update

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, sphinx, daemon

I'm using Sphinx RT index and MySQL DB, the issue I'm having now is that I need the data to be consistent and using regular inserts on both of them isn't the right way to it as I might end up with wrong index data or wrong db data.

Say you have the following table in MySQL DB

```
id, text
1, test is test
```

and you have the same in the RT index

```
id, text
```

the typical race condition that can happen here is when two users are updating the content at the same time.

So if user A updates with the following text

```
feeling good
```

and user B updates with the following text

```
nice whether
```

One of the many things that could happen is this

```
Update RT index with user A text 
Update DB table with user B text
Update RT index with user B text
Update DB table with user A text
```

So now when someone searches for a text, he will get the result from the index that is not there in the DB.

Is it ok to have a daemon in the middle that will be receiving UDP requests from the PHP page and the update the DB? something like below

```
php page --send both requests via UDP--> dameon 
php page <--send successful receive via UDP-- dameon 
daemon --send two MySQL updates request --> MySQL
```

Comment: Whats the point of the daemon? What problem does that solve?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with mysql locks. Lock the table before making the mysql update. Only release the lock once you've also sent the update to sphinx.

Might not scale if you have lots of concurrent updates, but for modest update rates should work fine.